# Как получить координаты метки в react когда меняется его положение?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Вот этот код работает у меня в react, но координаты метки не могу получить по событие dragend когда его перетаскивают:

```
<YMaps>
      <Map state={mapState} width={'100%'} height={600}>
        <Placemark
          geometry={{
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [55.753994, 37.622093]
          }}
          options={{
            preset: 'islands#redDotIcon',
            draggable: true
          }}
          events={{
            dragend:{function (event){
                console.log("function worket" + event.get(position));
              }}
          }}/>
      </Map>
    </YMaps>
```

В песочнице есть инструкция по этому адресу, но там по js показывает как получить координаты: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode. Как можно писать в react вот этот код:

```
myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
            getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onDragEnd={e => console.log(e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates())}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!